# How do I perform a data series analysis in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, time-series

Ideally I'd like to use [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) or SARIMAX (Seasonal AutoRegressive Integrated Moving Average with eXogenous regressors) on that data from Cassandra.

I wasn't able to google a working example about using either of these 2 frameworks with Cassandra.

The other option I can see is to create a shell script to run `.py` scripts once in a while to add data to Cassandra tables.

Comment: Please describe what is your particular problem - code throws an error, or something like. Right now the question is too broad.

Comment: I'd like to run a time series analysis using a data from Cassandra. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the Cassandra officially supported by this package? If not, you need to export data into format that is understandable by this package